# How to fix "Error: Reducers may not dispatch actions." in my ReactJS Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using my notes application. I want to load my notes from Firebase after logging in, and my notes are displayed after I successfully log in.

However, when I add a note, the app says "Error: Reducers may not dispatch actions.". How do I solve this issue? Since I need to listen when notes are added and add the received notes to my app list. The note is added regardless of the error.

I know what the error means, but there is no way around it. I need to load my notes whenever one is added from Firebase.

The error fires at this line:

```
store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: {
    notes: previousNotes
}});
```

**My reducer code:**

```
const initialState = {
SCREEN_CURRENT: "home",
authenticated: false,
database: app.database().ref().child('notities'),
notes: Array(0),
loading: true,

username: "",
email: "",
displayName: ""
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
console.log("Reducer running", action.type);

switch(action.type){
case "AUTH_LOGIN":
    if(action.payload.login === true){
        state = {
            ...state,
            authenticated: true,
            username: action.payload.username,
            email: action.payload.email,
            displayName: action.payload.displayName,
        }



    const previousNotes = Array(0);

    app.database().ref().child('notities').on('child_added', snap => {
        if(snap.val().username === state.email){
            console.log("DB_ADDED");
            previousNotes.push({
                id: snap.key,
                noteContent: snap.val().noteContent,
                modifiedDate: snap.val().modifiedDate
            });

            previousNotes.sort(function(a, b){
                if(a.modifiedDate > b.modifiedDate){
                    return -1;
                }

                if(a.modifiedDate < b.modifiedDate){
                    return 1;
                }

                return 0;
            });

            console.log("previousNotes", previousNotes);


            store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: {
                 notes: previousNotes
            }});

            /* Below does not work (I already tried)
            state = {
                ...state,
                notes: previousNotes,
                loading: false
            }
            */
        }
    });






} else {
    state = {
        ...state,
        authenticated: false,
        username: "",
        email: "",
        displayName: ""
    }
}
break;

return state;
}
```

Inside my `App.js`, I fire the dispatch action of "AUTH_LOGIN":

```
componentWillMount(){
    const previousNotes = Array(0);

    this.removeAuthListener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

    if(user){ 
        let displayName = (user.displayName != null ? user.displayName : user.email.slice(0, user.email.indexOf("@")));
        let username = (user.username === undefined ? user.email : user.username);
        let email = user.email;

        console.log(displayName);
        console.log(username);

    store.dispatch({ type: "AUTH_LOGIN", payload: {
      username, email, displayName, login: true
    } });

  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: "AUTH_LOGIN", payload: {
      login: false
    } });
  }
});
```

}

If anyone needs more info/code, or if I am unclear, please let me know and I will explain/show further.

Expected result: [image: Expected result]
Actual result: [image: Actual result]

Error: Reducers may not dispatch actions.

Comment: It works the first time I load my app. The moment when I add a note, the error message appears (crashing my app) and the note is added regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, once again, found my answer. But why does this work the way it does?

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/122

I should use the following code:

```
// store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: { notes: previousNotes }}); // Error: Reducers may not dipatch actions
setTimeout(() => { store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: { notes: previousNotes }}); }); // I should use this code
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this, I faced the same issue and this solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Actually dispatch should be triggered from your action file and not from reducer. In action you should do request to firebase. Once data returned from firebase,  you should dispatch from action and in reducer you should handle or assign that data to store variables.

If any confusion, please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Because setTimeout creates a separate thread. It does not matter from where it is called, it just dispatch whatever you call.  Any dispatch always triggers and jump to reducers. Generally if dispatch starts to call from reducer directly, than it will be an infinite loop in which it will call reducers again and again. That's why we should not trigger dispatch from reducer.